# Prestashop add login with gmail in website

Tags: authentication, gmail, prestashop, account

how can give clients the autoristation to create account and login with their gmail account in my PrestaShop website without using modules?

i didn't try any thing yet
and i need to fix this problem fast
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: A search for `PrestaShop Google SSO` returns plenty of results for this exact feature.